# Infinitely many positive numbers $N$ that are three-digit palindromes to two different bases at the same time

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

> Notice that the number $78$ is a three-digit palindrome when written in base $5$ since $(78)_{10} = (303)_5$; it is also a three-digit palindrome when written in base $7$ since $(78)_{10} = (141)_7$. Prove that there are infinitely many positive numbers $N$ that are three-digit palindromes to two different bases at the same time.

Let the two bases be $b_1$ and $b_2$. Then we must have $aba_{b_1} = cdc_{b_2}$ with the condition that $0 \leq a,b \leq b_1-1$ and $0 \leq c,d \leq b_2-1$. Expanding the given equation gives $$ab_1^2+bb_1+a = cb_2^2+db_2+c.$$ Thus $$a(b_1^2+1)+bb_1 = c(b_2^2+1)+db_2.$$ How can we find infinitely many solutions to this?

Comment: There are infinitely many $3$-digit palindromic numbers in two simultaneous bases even if $b_2=b_1\pm 1$ (even if you restrict the bases to be consecutive). This is also true if you look at $3$ consecutive number bases, but there are no examples for $4$ or more consecutive number bases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a lot of freedom in finding these solutions. For example, you can simply restrict to looking for infinitely many solutions with $a=1$. Take any $b>3$ and set $b_1:=b+1$. Then
$$ab_1^2+bb_1+a=2b^2+3b+2,$$
is a palindrome in base $b_1$ and in base $b$.